# Unable to use "TextToSpeech.speak()" method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I have used this code earlier. The same line was executing back then. 
But in this new application, the same line of code isn't executing. In fact, it gets crashed.

```
TextToSpeech TTS ;
String fail = "hey";
TTS.speak(fail ,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null,null);
```

^^ Above code isn't working

```
TextToSpeech TTS;
String SPEAKDRAW = "OH OHH DRAW";
TTS.speak(SPEAKDRAW, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null,null);
```

^^ The code above executes perfectly

Here is the LogCat of the crash.

```
2019-08-19 22:46:05.997 15712-15712/com.example.anonymous D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-08-19 22:46:06.002 15712-15712/com.example.anonymous E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.anonymous, PID: 15712
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(java.lang.CharSequence, int, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.anonymous.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:454)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6612)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6589)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25925)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2019-08-19 22:46:06.048 15712-15712/com.example.anonymous I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15712 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post complete activity code for better understanding.

Comment: Please share the crash log from the logcat.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have edited question .. added the logcat

Comment: @FurqanKhan that would be dangerous am afraid.. nested if else and a bit confusing.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the answer that I wrote?

Comment: You're sending the speak function to a TTS object that is not yet initialized.  How is that happening, exactly and what is the best way to avoid doing that in your case?  Nobody knows because you're not showing the full code of Main Activity.

Comment: Its done.. I hadn't initialized it... I had initialized it in the previous app... so sorry.. my mistake.. I apologize everyone

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the crash log, it is difficult to determine what is the exact problem here. However, I guess the TTS engine is not installed in your device where you are testing the feature. I am quoting from the [developers' documentation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html),

> Although all Android-powered devices that support the TTS
>   functionality ship with the engine, some devices have limited storage
>   and may lack the language-specific resource files. If a user wants to
>   install those resources, the TTS API enables an application to query
>   the platform for the availability of language files and can initiate
>   their download and installation. So upon creating your activity, a
>   good first step is to check for the presence of the TTS resources with
>   the corresponding intent.

Hence I would like to recommend you to check if the TTS engine is installed in your device using the following intent.

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

And check if the device is ready or not by overriding the `onActivityResult` function in your activity like the following.

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, I do not see any `new` statement where you have initialized your `TTS` variable. However, I think you have that as you told you have got it working previously.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have attached the logcat... Thankyou so much for this code but yes, I have another applications in which this same line works on the same mobile device.  Do you want more part of the logcat?

Comment: So did you check if the TTS engine is installed as I have suggested in the answer?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes... I'll check it ad get back\

Comment: Cool, let me know.

Comment: wasn't able to comprehend the code that you gave me. But I guess it is installed, cause there is no problem with other applications.

Comment: This is a null pointer exception. Hence you should check for `null` first. After that, I think, the TTS engine is taking some time to initialize. Can you retry the TTS after some time it has been initialized?

Comment: can you try after some time......... means? can you please explain that?

Comment: You can use a `Handler` along with a `postDelayed` method call so that you can call the `TTS.speak()` function after a certain amount of time (e.g. two seconds).

Comment: Its done.. I hadn't initialized it... I had initialized it in the previous app... so sorry.. my mistake.. I apologize everyone

Comment: Great to know that your problem got solved. I think I have mentioned that already in my answer. Check the last part of the answer.